# How do I convert an json string into list in dart?

Tags: dart

My string is in the from of "['Curry Me Up','Curry Culture']"
and I want to convert it in ['Curry Me Up','Curry Culture']

I have tried doing `json.decode("['Curry Me Up','Curry Culture']")`

but its giving me error FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

Answer (score 0):

The string you are trying to parse does not contain valid JSON since you must encapsulate strings with `"` in JSON and not `'`. So if you instead do this it will work:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final list = json.decode('["Curry Me Up","Curry Culture"]') as List;
  print(list); // [Curry Me Up, Curry Culture]
}
```